# How to apply strokes to the borders of a SVG element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple SVG element with an image and text inside, but I want to apply strokes on the border of the SVG element when the element is hovered on. But instead, the strokes are being applied to the rest that contains the image and also the text element in the SVG.

```html
<style>
   svg{
       outline: none;
       border: 1px solid red;
       position: absolute;
       background: transparent;
       cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150 480;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  
   }    

   svg:hover {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  background: #4F95DA;
  stroke-dashoffset: -480;
}
</style>

<svg width="287" height="131" viewBox="0 0 287 131" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="Menu2">
<rect id="briefcase 1" x="118" y="22" width="51" height="51" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<text id="label1" fill="black" xml:space="preserve" style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0em"><tspan x="84" y="107.652">Create Account</tspan></text>
</g>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="scale(0.002)"/>
</pattern>
<image id="image0" data-name="briefcase.png" width="500" height="500" xlink:href="briefcase.png"/>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: The question is not clear ... Do you just need to replace the red border color when hovering?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov not really, i want white strokes to animate over the border when the button is hovered. currently the white strokes animate around the image and the text instead

Comment: Instead of applying it to the svg element try `svg:hover #briefcase1 {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  stroke-dashoffset: -480;
}`

Comment: @enxaneta thanks, but that won't work. it'll only apply the transitions on the borders of image. I need them on the red border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply drawing lines on the borders of the SVG and then applying strokes on the lines.

```html
<style>
    svg{
        outline: none;
        /* border: 1px solid red; */
        position: absolute;
        background: transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
   left: 10;
   top: 0;
   fill: none;       
   stroke-dasharray: 150 480;
   stroke-dashoffset: 150;
   transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    }    

    .lines{
        stroke: black;
    }
 
    svg:hover {
   transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
   background: #ddd;;
   stroke-dashoffset: -480;
 }
 </style>


<svg width="287" height="131" viewBox="0 0 287 131" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Menu2" clip-path="url(#clip0)">
    <rect id="briefcase 1" x="118" y="22" width="51" height="51" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
    <text id="label1" fill="black" xml:space="preserve" style="white-space: pre" font-family="Roboto" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="0em"><tspan x="84" y="107.652">Create Account</tspan></text>
    <line id="Line1" class="lines" x1="0.5" x2="0.5" y1="0.5" y2="131"/>
    <line id="Line2" class="lines" x1="0.5" x2="286"  y1="0.5"  y2="0.5"/>
    <line id="Line3" class="lines" y1="130" x1="0.5" x2="286" y2="130"/>
    <line id="Line4" class="lines" x1="286" x2="286" y1="0.5" y2="130" />
    </g>
    <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
    <use xlink:href="#image0" transform="scale(0.002)"/>
    </pattern>
    <clipPath id="clip0">
    <rect width="286.55" height="131" fill="white"/>
    </clipPath>
    <image id="image0" data-name="briefcase.png" width="500" height="500" xlink:href="briefcase.png"/>
    </defs>
    </svg>
```